# Firebase storage rules error: Error saving rules - Undefined parameter - ERRORS

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I want my files in firebase storage to be public for download without need to be authenticated user.

The default rules are:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

According to the example [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start) I changed it to:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

But I get the following strange error:

***Error saving rules - Undefined parameter - ERRORS***

Anyone know what can be the problem?

Comment: Hi,
I copied your rules and it seems working in "my" Firebase.  
Did you put it here exactly how you've written it in Firebase?

Comment: I tried to do it with VPN (as you suggested) to pass my Internet provider (Rimon) and now it works. Thanks